# Upload with progress percentage does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a upload progress bar but it does not work this function     `xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e){...})`... response error error undefined

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                console.log(e.loaded + " / " + e.total)
            }
        }, false);


        return xhr;
    },
    type: "POST",
    url: server + '/api/UserFiles/UploadFile',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: data,
    success: function (result) {
        alert("Uploaded Success");

    },
    error: function (err) {

        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

on the consol the respones is: Error  error  undefined

Comment: You're not passing anything called `err` in the error callback, just `(xhr, status, p3, p4)`.

Comment: Did you edit the code to match my comment, or is the original code the code you wrote? If so, you should leave it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't correctly implement the error handler: in your example you attempt to log a variable called `err` which doesn't exist.

(Edit: Ok, even with the edited code, keep reading.)

[According to documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), it should instead be:

```
error: function (xhr, textStatus, thrownError) {
  console.log(xhr.status);
  console.error(thrownError);
}
```

As a side comment, don't use `alert()`: it's not nearly as powerful as the [console API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference) which can do amazing things like print data tables, run timers, show stack traces, and so on.